# async_eb_func v.s. async_tm_func

Tags: c++, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am reading some thrift service code and found a lot of names like this:

```
async_eb_function_name(...) or async_tm_function_name(...)
```

What are they? It seems to me the prefix: async_eb_ and  async_tm_ are both auto added. What are they and what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

That's from the Python-version of the generator.

EB seems to mean "event based" and "TM" ... well, not 100% sure, but some other code in that same file seems to indicate that "T" might stand for "thread".

References:

- `eb` vs `tm` [thrift/compiler/py/generate/t_cpp_generator.py line 1081](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift/blob/master/thrift/compiler/py/generate/t_cpp_generator.py#L1081)
- `def _is_processed_in_eb` [thrift/compiler/py/generate/t_cpp_generator.py line 5726](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift/blob/master/thrift/compiler/py/generate/t_cpp_generator.py#L5726)
- `processInThread` [thrift/compiler/py/generate/t_cpp_generator.py line 1694](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift/blob/master/thrift/compiler/py/generate/t_cpp_generator.py#L1694)